# member function pointers c++

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I've looked at the top answers c++ to Visitor pattern and to pointers to member functions; but I still cannot get how the following (rather simple) scenario should be designed.

In a basic example, I want to have an optimizer class. Given a member function of another class, it find some optimal value. Something like this:

```
class Optimizer{
    public:
        typedef double (*Func1d)(double);
        typedef double (*Func2d)(double,double);
        void Optimize1d(Func1d* f1Ptr, double& x);
        void Optimize2d(Func2d* f2Ptr, double& x, double& y);
};
```

and two example classes:

```
class A {
    double A1d(double x){return x;}
};

class B{
    double B2d(double x, double y){return x+y;}
};
```

and the main function, which I would like to be able to use as follows:

```
void main()
{
    Optimizer opt;
    double xA_opt, xB_opt, yB_opt;
    opt.Optimize1d(&A::A1d,xA_opt);
    opt.Optimize2d(&B::B2d, xB_opt, yB_opt);
}
```

But still, I can't get it to work. I don't want the optimizer to directly hold pointers to objects of type A and B; because then he needs to be familiar with these objects.

I hope this question makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Why function pointers and not virtual functions and an interface?

Comment: I'm not 'married' to function pointers. this is why I think it's a design question rather than an implementation one. Perhaps I should re-tag. I would appreciate suggestions!

Comment: Can those functions be static (A::A1d, B::B2d )?

Comment: Unfortunately not; I'd like them to depend the on inner state of a given object.

Comment: you may try with std::bind and place holders for 1 and 2 arguments respectively then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `typedef double (*Func1d)(double);` is not a member-function-pointer but just a plain function-pointer.

If you used a real member-function-pointer, the function would also have to have an instance of `A` or `B` which you say you don't want.

If you can't make `A1d` and `B2d` static the other options are to make your `Optimize1d` and `Optimize2d` template functions taking a templated functor:

```
template<typename F>
void Optimize1d(F f1, double& x);
template<typename F>
void Optimize2d(F f2, double& x, double& y);
```

or a `std::function`:

```
void Optimize1d(std::function<double(double)> f1, double& x);
void Optimize2d(std::function<double(double, double)> f2, double& x, double& y);
```

Both can be called with a lambda capturing an instance of `A` or `B`:

```
A a;
B b;
opt.Optimize1d([&a](double x){return a.A1d(x); }, xA_opt);
opt.Optimize2d([&b](double x, double y){return b.B2d(x, y); }, xB_opt, yB_opt);
```

**Edit:**
If you don't have C++11 you could define your own functor using a class which defines an `operator()` instead of a lambda. The class will have to store a pointer or reference to an instance of `A` or `B` in a member variable:

```
struct A1d {
    A* a;
    A1d(A& a) : a(&a) {}
    double operator()(double x) { return a->A1d(x); }
};
```

You can then construct an instance of this class and pass it to the templated optimize functions:

```
A1d a1d(a);  
opt.Optimize1d(a1d,xA_opt);
```

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Qn10Dww0GY7ayQil)

perhaps you could even make your `A` or `B` classes functors themselves by adding an `operator()` function to them?

Comment: Is there a way to convert `double a.A1d(double)` (member function of a particular instance) to `std::function<double(double)>` without using a lambda to capture the instance?

Comment: @user3528438 you could just use std::bind. but you need to have some kind of "capture" where (a reference to) an object of type A gets stored in the function pointer object. there's not that much difference between lambda capture and std::bind in this regard

Comment: @Chris Drew: Thanks for your answer. Would you possible elaborate on the templated solution for a non-C++11 solution?

Comment: @zuuz Done. I've also added a link to a live demo of all my suggestions.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the demo and extra explanation :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem in the above code is that in C++, pointer-to-member functions are a distinct type, incompatible with "regular" function pointers.

This typedef

```
typedef double (*Func1d)(double);
```

is legal in both C and C++ code, and you can use C-style "free" functions with this type.

But at this line in your main function:

```
opt.Optimize1d(&A::A1d,xA_opt);
```

you are trying to pass a pointer to member function as a `Func1d` and that can't be done. For one thing, you can't invoke a pointer to member function without a pointer to an object of that type as well, and you would have to pass that also.

The simplest thing is to include header `<functional>` and use `std::function<double(double)>` for this. (Assuming you have C++11, otherwise you could use `boost::function`.)

There are other things you could do like use virtual member dispatch as suggested in comments. (IMO that's a little less elegant.)

You could also make the `optimize` functions be template functions, and accept an object of the templated type etc. etc. But really `std::function` is the way to go here, it will handle all those details for you.